# What should be the maven archetype of a Custom AutoLogin for LifeRay

Tags: maven, liferay, autologin, maven-archetype, archetypes

I found several archetypes in maven for LifeRay development. can anyone help me to find the most suitable archetype for custom AutoLogin.

Which contains a AutoLogin Filter and AutoLogin hook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both these artifacts are part of a hook plugin, so the most suitable maven artifact would be *liferay-hook*: https://repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/repositories/liferay-ce/com/liferay/maven/archetypes/liferay-hook-archetype/